# Clopen subspaces of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

Following a paper of Van Douwen called "Characterizations of $\beta \mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta \mathbb{R}$", where he is proving some properties for specific spaces, I would like to know whether other spaces have the same property.

**My question:** Is every clopen subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

The author claims this **is** true for $\mathbb{Q}$, but I am not sure, whether it still holds for $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ = $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$. I think yes, but cannot tell a proof.

Thank you for your insights.

**Edit:** For $\mathbb{Q}$, I assume the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. For $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$, I primarly assume the product topology, but also interested in the case with the topology inherited from $l^2$ (induced by the norm on $l^2$).

Comment: Please specify the topology on these spaces, if we are to answer questions about open/closed sets. For instance, as a subspace $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology generated by open intervals, $\mathbb{Q}$ has the discrete topology. Every subset is clopen!

Comment: Yes, for $\mathbb{Q}$, I assume the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. I think this is also why the claim is true for $\mathbb{Q}$, as you said, any subset is clopen. For $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$, I assume the topology inherited from $l^2$ (induced by the norm on $l^2$).

Comment: You switched spaces? The norm topology is very different from the product topology (you aked about earlier) and has another name: Erdös space. It has dim=ind=Ind equal to $1$ not $0$!

Comment: Sorry, made an edit, I assume the most common topology, which is probably the product one.  Thank you for pointing at this.

Comment: If van Douwen uses $\Bbb Q^\omega$ it's for sure the product topology or he would have used Erdös space as its name. Why are you interested in that space in particular ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\Bbb Q$ this is true because it's a theorem by Sierpiński that any countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. Any open subset of $\Bbb Q$ obeys that property.

In a comment on an earlier question on this space I noted that for $\Bbb Q^\omega$ (in the product topology!) there also is a more technical characterisation of that space along these lines (the irrationals $\Bbb P$ and the Cantor set also have such characterisations): If $X$ is a separable metrisable zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma\delta}$ that is nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and of the first category (in itself), then $X \simeq \Bbb Q^\omega$. So to prove your hunch it would suffice that any open subset of $\Bbb Q^\omega$ also obeys the aforementioned properties. Separable metrisable zero-dimensional are immediate. The others I would have to think a bit more about. I won't rule out that your hunch is correct.

Your space (with inherited topology from $\ell_2$) is called (incomplete) Erdös space. It has dimension $1$ and not $0$. Many papers have been written about characterisations of it. Look for them online..

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.05874.pdf) might be of interest. Many good references too. Your space is denoted $\mathfrak{E}$ there.

Comment: Thank you! I think the first category (also called meagre) is clear too, since every subset of a meagre set is also meagre, so it holds for open subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ I guess.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova yes the meagre part is also clear. So it seems like the rational sequences are strongly homogeneous. Sort of expected.

Comment: Could you please provide a source or author of the claim that you mentioned in your answer? "If $X$ is a separable metrisable zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma\delta}$ that is nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and of the first category (in itself), then $X \simeq \Bbb Q^\omega$."

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma (I wanted to tag you in the comment above as well) I found a paper "Countable products of zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma \delta}$ spaces " by Engelen (1984) in which one lemma says that $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ is strongly homogeneous (i.e. for each non-empty clopen subset $U$ of $X$, $U \simeq X$). So the characterization in your answer may be overkill? Or is it equivalent somehow?